# FindByIndexNameSessionRepository not available in spring reactive stack

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway as BFF and spring redis for sessions. Since FindByIndexNameSessionRepository is not available in spring reactive stack, how can I delete session of user from redis. In some cases I want to delete or invalidate session of user so that user has to login again.